# How to put Return Statement into block using clang

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to parse C files and add debugs at exit points of the functions using clang.

I can add debugs just before return, or exit of function using following code

```
if (isa<ReturnStmt>(s)) {
  ReturnStmt *ReturnStatement = cast<ReturnStmt>(s);
  TheRewriter.InsertText(ReturnStatement->getLocStart(), "{printf(\"[%s:%d] OUT \\n\", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);\n", true, true);
}
```

But it doesn't work for functions like this:

```
//before preprocessing
int foo(int a)
{
  if(a)
    return 1;
  else
    return a;
}
//after
int foo(int a)
{
  if(a)
    {printf("[%s:%d] OUT \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return 1;
  else
    {printf("[%s:%d] OUT \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    return a;
}
```

Unfortunately, simple getLocEnd doesn't work.

```
TheRewriter.InsertText(ReturnStatement->getLocEnd(), "}", true, true);
```

it puts "}" just after "return".

```
 if(a)
 {printf("[%s:%d] OUT \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
 return }1;
```

Please, help me to detect end of Return Statement location, to put closing "}" or maybe it's less difficult to put ReturnStatement into some Compound Statement or so.

I also tried find end of Return Statement like this:

```
ReturnStatement->getLocStart().getLocWithOffset(strlen(retvalue) + 1);
```

but I can get return value in a string view only for ImplicitCastExpr.

Thanks.

Comment: `ReturnStatement->getRetValue()->getLocEnd()` probably won't help; as that would produce `return 1};`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it still gives `return }0;`

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Stmt-getLocEnd-td4030189.html) with no simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

here we have an answer. I found it here:
https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/blob/master/CIrewriter.cpp

all you need is :

```
// Note Stmt::getLocEnd() returns the source location prior to the
// token at the end of the line.  For instance, for:
// var = 123;
//      ^---- getLocEnd() points here.

SourceLocation END = stmt->getLocEnd();

// MeasureTokenLength gets us past the last token, and adding 1 gets
// us past the ';'.
int offset = Lexer::MeasureTokenLength(END,
                                       TheRewriter.getSourceMgr(),
                                       TheRewriter.getLangOpts()) + 1;

SourceLocation END1 = END.getLocWithOffset(offset);
TheRewriter.InsertText(END1, "\n}", true, true);
```